# Selecting a series of strings separated by <br> within a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyway for me to grab each of those strings using Jquery or Javascript?.. 'fight club', 33 main, houston etc etc

```
 <span class="cart_text2">
    Fight Club
    <br>
    33 main,
    <br>
    houston,
    <br>
    TX US
    <br>
    Phone Number: 777-888-9999
    <br>
    Email: abc@test.com
   </span>
```

Comment: If possible, surely changing the markup is more efficient? then the selecting is easy.

Comment: I agree with @user319940 , implementing a better markup is by far the best solution because then your _HTML_ would be describing the data.

Answer (score 1):

Select the `.childNodes` of the parent, and iterate the collection. The text nodes will have a `.nodeType` of  `3`. Then use the `.data` property to fetch the text from the node.

```
var elems = document.querySelector(".cart_text2").childNodes;
var result = [];

for (var i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (elems[i].nodeType === 3)
        result.push(elems[i].data);
}
```

I used `.querySelector` instead of `getElementsByClassName` in order to support IE8.

---

Using `.innerHTML` will depend on the browser's particular HTML rendering for the `br` element. Traversing the DOM is safer.

---

With jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
var result = $(".cart_text2").contents().map(function(i, node) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3)
        return node.data;
}).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_text2')[0].innerHTML.split('<br>');
console.log(elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the *Node* with class `cart_text2`, then split the `innerHTML` with `<br>` and possibly do some whitespace trimming

```
var node = document.getElementsByClassName('cart_text2')[0],
    strs = node.innerHTML.split(/<br\s*\/?>/);
```

Then say you have `String.prototype.trim` or some polyfill

```
strs = strs.map(function (e) {return e.trim();});
```

The *RegExp* I used in the `split` is to cover possible instances of `<br>`, `<br/>` and `<br />`